# Problems with Now 2 migration

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, vercel

As [stated here](https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/problems-with-now-2-migration~9abbf7fa-740a-434e-a02b-d06e3bc24a88) on Spectrum, I'm having troubles in migrating my Next website from an Express custom server to Now. My problem is that I'm unable to get the home page, because I'm trying to send URL params, with no success. I need to pass a `lang` parameter, as follows:

```
localhost:3000/en
```

Then, I would have to get the Home as expected. But I'm receiving this exception:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'lang' of undefined at Function.getInitialProps (/Users/lucacattide/Vagrant/debian/public/LC/front-end/.next/server/static/development/pages/_document.js:1111:32)

That's because I was previously reading the `ctx.req.params.lang` parameter from `_document.js` `getInitialProps` for various reasons. Even by replacing it with `ctx.req.query.lang` I'm still getting it.

I'm currently copying two examples both by Zeit migration guide and article. As both suggest, I'm trying the `API` approach (https://zeit.co/guides/migrate-to-zeit-now/) and the `pages` one too (https://zeit.co/guides/custom-next-js-server-to-routes/).
In the API one, I've implemented inside `/api` path, the `[lang].js` segment, with the following content:

```
module.exports = (req, res) => {
  res.send(req.query.lang);
}
```

Then with the `/pages` one, I copied and renamed the `index.js` to `[lang].js` inside the same path, and replaced the `req.query.lang` as mentioned above. Both of these doesn't work. I'm stuck with the same exception, that warns about `_document.js`. I need that because of different processes inside it, so deleting it isn't an option in my case.
Of course I'm testing on Now environment (running `now dev`) on my `localhost`. The app works perfectly on Express, so I hope to solve this issue in order to deploy it correctly on Now.

Anyone experienced this before or could help me with some suggestion?

Thanks in advance for support.

**EDIT:**

I tried to force paths too by defining routes in `now.json` but the result is the same. Here my current configuration:

```
{
  "public": false,
  "name": "LC",
  "version": 2,
  "routes": [{
    "src": "/(?<lang>[^/]+)",
    "dest": "/?lang=$lang"
  }]
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

I switched all inside `pages` dir as suggested from 2nd guide, because I wasn't getting nothing from `/api`. Trying by placing only a `[lang].js` route and removing routes definitions from `now.json`.

At this moment, by inspecting the `req` object I receive an empty one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to Now platform updates - v2 - I noticed that a lot of Next API parts has changed. By revamping my code in order to following the new approaches, I'm able to get the previously missing parameter.
In details, I followed the API routes tips on the [latest official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs#api-routes)

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the passing the lang like this `localhost:3000/en` then use below snippet to access this

```
req.params.lang
```

But if you are passing the lang like this `localhost:3000?lang=en`

Then use this

```
req.query.lang
```

Comment: Thanks @iamadeveloper, as I mentioned I've tried it but unfortunately I'm still getting the exception

Comment: Try to print your request object `console.dir(req)`

Comment: Zeit.co documentation states that ```req.params``` is not longer supported by their API. Anyway, trying with both ```query/params```, ```req``` results empty.